# Matching condition out of a recursive closure - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, closures

I was looking to get a second pair of eyes to look at this recursive call that searches for a specific value in a binary tree.

```
public func findMatchingCondition(_ process: (T) -> (Bool)) {
    switch self {
    case .empty: break
    case let .node(left, value, right):
        let condition = process(value)

        // If the height is 1 then reurn we found our matching or last condition
        if height < 2 {
            return
        }

        if condition {
            right.findMatchingCondition(process)
        } else {
            left.findMatchingCondition(process)
        }
    }
}
```

The above function transverses through a binary tree and if the condition is true then processes the right side, if not then processes the left side.

```
var someEnum: SomeEnum? = nil
tree.findMatchingCondition {
    someEnum = $0
    return $0.value(inputValueToGetBool)
}
```

So my binary tree consists of enums and enums have a function called `value` that returns a bool if the input matches a condition.

So what I want to do is transverse the tree and return that specific enum if it's height is 1.

**Question: Is there a better to do the above than setting an optional `someEnum?` and then passing that into the closure?**

Please let me know if I am explaining this properly! I can re-edit to explain better.

**EDIT:**

Grabbing height:

```
enum BinaryTree<T: Comparable> {

    case empty
    indirect case node(BinaryTree<T>, T, BinaryTree<T>)

    /* Distance of this node to its lowest leaf. Performance: O(n). */
    public var height: Int {
        switch self {
        case .empty: return 0
        case let .node(left, _, right): return 1 + max(left.height, right.height)
        }
    }

}
```

**Possible Solutions:**

Maybe use an `inout` parameter?

Comment: How do you plan on getting the `height` value? I don't see it defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Easy to do that, I just added the code

Comment: What's the problem? Is it that `findMatchingCondition` takes a process that returns a Bool but you also need to return an enum? So in that case, isn't the problem that you need to return two values? And in that case, isn't that what a tuple is for?

Comment: I don't think you need the `height < 2` part. If `height` is 1, the recursion on both `left` and `right` will see `empty` and break. And calculating height is nontrivial—it bumps an O(log(n)) avg / O(n) worst case algorithm to O(n*log(n)) / O(n^3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to update a variable from inside the closure that you pass around. If you want something more functional, you can use something like

```
func traverse(until: (BinaryTree<T>) -> Bool, decision: (BinaryTree<T>) -> Bool) -> T? {
    switch tree {

    case .empty:
        return nil

    case let .node(left, value, right):

        if until(self) {
            return value
        } else {
            let nextNode = decision(self) ? left : right
            return nextNode.traverse(until: until, decision: decision)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can get your value with

```
let value = tree.traverse(
    until: { $0.height == 1 }, 
    decision: { $0.value == inputValueToGetBool }
)
```